# How to use specific (or custom) versions in requirements in buildozer.spec?

Tags: kivy, buildozer

I am building an application that uses plyer library. However, I have modified plyer library in my own branch of github. My question is how to specify in the buildozer.spec file that I need plyer to be downloaded from my path not the default branch.

Regards,

Comment: Edit your buildozer.spec and add "requirements = plyer,kivy" under "(list) Application requirements"

Comment: yes, but when u put plyer for example, it will use pip install plyer, I don't want this version, I need a specific version of github

Answer (score 2):

You can specify the version as such

```
requirements = python2,kivy==1.10.1,plyer==0.1.0
```

Comment: Works well, even with kivy==2.0.0rc1. But is it possible to elaborate version of Python same way, e.g. 3.8.1?

Comment: But **not** with ranges, e.g. `requirements = python3,yarl<2.0,>=1.0` or even `yarl<2.0` (tested with Buildozer 1.4.0)